# Vim search and substitute

Tags: vim

I have an example:

```
a, an [e, en]
and [end]
afraid [e'freid]
...
```

Is it possible to search only in the brackets? And in those letters replaced?
I would like to combine the search with replacement > `/\[.*\]` and `:%s/e/ə/gc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
:%s/\[\zs.*\ze\]/\=substitute(submatch(0), 'e', 'ə', 'g')/
```

Unfortunately I don't know a way to get `/c` to work in there.

Alternatively,

```
:%s/\%(\[.*\)\@<=e\%(.*\]\)\@=/ə/gc
```

This one is a bit "brute force" and may run slower on very long lines.

Comment: the first one can be improved as `\[\zs[^]]*\ze\]` to limit match within `[]` only.. for ex: `a, an [e, en] enable ]` should the `e` in `enable` be changed as well?

Comment: @Sundeep According to OP's original search pattern, yes.

Answer (score 0):

One way (from command mode) :

```
:!perl -i -pe 'BEGIN{ sub f {$_ = shift; s/e/a/g; return "[$_]" }}; s/\[(.*?)\]/f($1)/e' %
```

Comment: Wrapping a subroutine definition in `BEGIN { }` is pointless.

Comment: Your subroutine overwrites (`$_ = shift`) the string you're currently replacing in (`s///`). If that actually works, it's certainly not good style.

Answer (score 0):

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) provides a `:SubstituteInSearch` (among many more) command. It's basically a simplification of @melpomene's answer.

```
:%SubstituteInSearch/\[.*\]/e/ə/gc
```